# Adding record using entity framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, edmx

I am using EF4 in VS2010 and I have the following code:

```
PatientInformation patientInformation = PatientInformation.CreatePatientInformation(3); 
patientInformation.DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1983, 6, 13);
patientInformation.FamilyId = 1;
patientInformation.FirstName = "First";
patientInformation.LastName = "Patient";

ClinicEntity.PatientInformations.AddObject(patientInformation);
ClinicEntity.SaveChanges();
```

The problem is that `AddObject()` is not adding the object to the collection and I just can't figure out why. It does not give any error either.

The only non-nullable field in my SQL Server database is the `PatientId` column, which is an identity column... Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Yogesh Lotlikar

Comment: an you show us the implementation of `AddObject()`. I am assuming its custom implementation?

Comment: Can you show us the **connection string** you're using for your EF database?

Comment: @marc_s here is the connection string - <add name="eClinicEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/eClinicDataModel.csdl|res://*/eClinicDataModel.ssdl|res://*/eClinicDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=YOGESH-PC\HOME;initial catalog=eClinic;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: @KomengeMwandila - It is not a custom implementation. The AddObject comes with ObjectContext class which is inherited by the entity class

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ClinicEntity.PatientInformations.Add(patientInformation);
```

Comment: I am not getting the .Add method. It only gives me .AddObject()

Comment: AddObject is not working. I have even tried using the below code ClinicEntity.AddToPatientInformations(patientInformation); Though this is a deprecated method, it neither gives an error nor inserts record in the DB.

Comment: @Yogi, thought you're using EF 4.1+

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what is going on with this line:

```
PatientInformation patientInformation = PatientInformation.CreatePatientInformation(3);
```

What happens if you do something like this as a test instead:

```
    PatientInformation patientInformation = new PatientInformation();
    patientInformation.DateOfBirth = new DateTime(1983, 6, 13);
    patientInformation.FamilyId = 1;
    patientInformation.FirstName = "First";
    patientInformation.LastName = "Patient";

    ClinicEntity.PatientInformations.AddObject(patientInformation);
    ClinicEntity.SaveChanges();
```

If that test code works, you need to rework whatever is going on in the CreatePatientInformation(3) call.

Comment: You should fire up a copy of sql profiler and see what, if any, calls are being made to the database then. Copy the generated sql you capture and run it from SSMS and see if you get any better error messages.

Comment: Checked with the profiler; There are no entries generated for inserting this record.